# The Plain HttP Request sent to Https port for passbolt deployment

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, k3s

I have an issue when deploying passbolt on Kubernetes through helm chart.  ( I use rancher for the management UI)

Nginx controller in used for k8s ingress and target port is 443 on passbolt service.

Badluck, I show this "400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" when accessing my passbolt subdomain.

Below is my yaml for ingress :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: >-
      [{"addresses":["172.10.100.11"],"port":443,"protocol":"HTTPS","serviceName":"default:my-release-passbolt","ingressName":"default:main-ing","hostname":"passbolt.ridhoswasta.com","path":"/","allNodes":false}]
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
  creationTimestamp: '2024-03-20T15:48:20Z'
  generation: 2
  managedFields:
    - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:status:
          f:loadBalancer:
            f:ingress: {}
      manager: nginx-ingress
      operation: Update
      subresource: status
      time: '2024-03-20T15:48:21Z'
    - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: {}
            f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: {}
        f:spec:
          f:rules: {}
          f:tls: {}
      manager: agent
      operation: Update
      time: '2024-03-20T15:53:00Z'
  name: main-ing
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: '43437392'
  uid: 7d6f120e-b7f2-4850-97a6-386ec8f41bd6
spec:
  rules:
    - host: passbolt.ridhoswasta.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: my-release-passbolt
                port:
                  number: 443
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - passbolt.ridhoswasta.com
      secretName: tls-secret
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 172.10.100.11
```

I have tried everything suggestion on the online but nothing can fix this now.

below is the nginx logs :

```
125.165.104.162 - - [20/Mar/2024:15:53:07 +0000] "GET /auth/is-authenticated.json HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
125.165.104.162 - - [20/Mar/2024:15:54:07 +0000] "GET /users/me.json?api-version=v2 HTTP/1.1" 400 650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I don't see anything wrong even I've already followed trick from https://community.passbolt.com/t/400-bad-request-the-plain-http-request-was-sent-to-https-port/8684/3

and still no luck with that.

What could be wrong here?